# How to install python 3.7 32Bit with VirtualEnv on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

How to install a version of the python environment 3.7 32Bit with VirtualEnv on windows 10?

I need to use ctypes to load a DLL in 32Bits

```
from ctypes import *

WinDLL("ProfitDLL")
```

> OSError: [WinError 193]% 1 is not a valid Win32 application

I believe it is the architecture of the python version on my machine to have installed python 64Bit

Could anyone help?

I thank you for your help and attention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install a separate 23Bit version of Python on my Windows system.